# How can we keep consistency in project datasets manifest definition and the actual schema inside the target project?

Tags: ruby, json, sdk, automation, gooddata

Must the project datasets json manifest file always be described also about already defined datasets inside the target project, or, only be described about the very direct target datasets to be uploaded data by the Ruby script, and which is not yet defined at the target project?

Is there only one-sided manner of external dataset schema declaration in manipulating (specifying) the target dataset to be uploaded data by the external Ruby script, and none of the way in referring how already defined project dataset schema should be referred from outside of the project by external Ruby script in compatible manner among active GoodData project dataset schema, CloudConnect's LDM modeler and dataset manifest file of Ruby automation SDK, therefore isn't there any mean in keeping consistency of dataset schema declaration methods among those but only successful consideration to avoid conflict among them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your first question:

I'm not sure if I clearly understand the question, dataset manifests are typically generated by the platform. The only case in which manifests have to be modified is when you need to make them fit some of the formats of your data. Could you explain me what you are trying to do and what you need exactly to do with the manifests?

In regard to your second question:
You mentioned three different concepts "GoodData project dataset schema, CloudConnect's LDM modeler and dataset manifest file of Ruby automation SDK"

Then you asked: "isn't there any mean in keeping consistency of dataset schema declaration methods among those but only successful consideration to avoid conflict among them?"

Can you describe precisely which conflict you mean?